# How to load custom script in Next.js 13

Tags: javascript, next.js

In Next.js 13 I have a website and all of this website's components are server components.

There one need for observing scroll and on it doing some stuff.

I don't use third-party libraries like `wow.js` for this and I have my own custom script.

Let's say this is my script:

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.scroll, .scroll-once')
elements.forEach(element => {
    const on = (element.getAttribute('on') || '100') / 100
    observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
        entries.forEach(entry => {
            if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                // logic for entering
            }
            else {
                // logic for exiting
            }
        })
    }, {
        root: null,
        rootMargin: '0px',
        threshold: on > 0 && on < 1 ? on : 1
    })
    observer.observe(element)
})
```

I moved script into `script.js` and placed it inside `/public/scripts` directory.

Then using `next/script` I imported it at the end of my `layout.js`:

```
import Script from 'next/script'


<Script src="/scripts/scroll.js"></Script>
</body>
```

However, when I run it, I see 404 for `/scripts/scroll.js`.

What should I do?

Comment: is your script really in the public folder? check console what url  its trying to load from and make sure your script really exists there

Comment: @Breezer, yes, it's in `/public/scripts/scroll.js` file. I can go to the root directory of my project and `cat public/scripts/scroll.js` and it works.

Comment: what if you move your scroll.js in another folder? i think `next/script` cant load scripts from public folder

Comment: @Nico, did it and it does not work. Of course anything that needs to be served statically needs to go into the `public` directory.